# How to cover code coverage for the below Rest API where used for DOM Deserialization

Tags: apex, code-coverage

MY Class:-

```
@RestResource (urlmapping = '/UpdateBill/*')
global without sharing class ApiUpdateClass{
    
    @HttpPost
    global static void updateBill(){
        try{
             RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
             RestRequest     restRqst = RestContext.request;
             String xml = restRqst.requestBody.toString();
             DOM.Document doc = new DOM.Document();
             doc.load(xml);
             Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();
             List<OrderDetail> objOrderDetail=new List<OrderDetail>();
             for(Dom.XMLNode child : address.getChildElements()) 
             {
                 String billNumber = child.getChildElement('BILLNUMBER', null).getText();
                 String doNumber = child.getChildElement('DONUMBER', null).getText();
                 OrderDetail obj=new OrderDetail();
                 obj.billNumber=billNumber;
                 obj.doNumber=doNumber;
                 objOrderDetail.add(obj);
             }
            Map<string,string> orderDetailMap=new Map<string,string>();
            List<Delivery_Order__c> upodateableList = new List<Delivery_Order__c>();
            if(objOrderDetail !=null && !objOrderDetail.isEmpty())
            {
                for(OrderDetail obj:objOrderDetail)
                {
                    orderDetailMap.put(obj.doNumber,obj.billNumber);
                }
                List<Delivery_Order__c> objOrderList = [Select id,Name,Bill_Number__c From Delivery_Order__c Where Name in :orderDetailMap.keySet()];
                for(Delivery_Order__c obj:objOrderList)
                {
                    if(orderDetailMap.containsKey(obj.Name))
                    {
                        obj.Bill_Number__c = orderDetailMap.get(obj.Name);
                        obj.Status__c ='Bill Generated';
                        upodateableList.add(obj);
                    }    
                }              
                if(!upodateableList.isEmpty())
                {
                    database.update(upodateableList);
                    RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{"success":"Update successfully"}');
                }        
            }
            else
            {
                RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{"error":"There is something went wrong"}');
            }    
            //RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{"error":"'+objOrderDetailList+'"}');        
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('error >> '+e.getMessage()+'at line >> '+e.getLineNumber());
        }
    }
    
    global class  OrderDetail{
        global string billNumber;
        global string doNumber;
    }

    global class OrderInfo{
        global List<OrderDetail> ORDERDT { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Test Class:-

```
@isTest
public class ApiUpdateClass_Test {
 
    public static testmethod void setup() {
        Test.startTest();
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        request.requestUri ='https://uat-restexplorer.cs32.force.com/services/apexrest/UpdateBill';
        request.httpMethod = 'POST';
        request.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        RestContext.request = request;
        RestContext.response = res;
        
        ApiUpdateClass.OrderInfo oinfor = new ApiUpdateClass.OrderInfo();
        ApiUpdateClass.OrderDetail od= new ApiUpdateClass.OrderDetail();
        List<ApiUpdateClass.OrderDetail> OrderDetailList = new List<ApiUpdateClass.OrderDetail>();
        
        Delivery_Order__c oderObj = new Delivery_Order__c();
        oderObj.Bill_Number__c = '234';
       // oderObj.Name = '123';
        oderObj.Pincode__c= '123233';
        oderObj.From_Address__c = 'Banipark,Jaipur-302016';
        oderObj.To_Address__c='AJMER NH-8';
        oderObj.Date_Of_Delivery__c = system.today();
        oderObj.Status__c = 'Sent to Tally';
        oderObj.GST__c = '24AAACC1206D1ZM';
        insert oderObj;
        oderObj = [Select id ,Name,Bill_Number__c,Pincode__c,From_Address__c,To_Address__c,Date_Of_Delivery__c,Status__c,GST__c from Delivery_Order__c where Bill_Number__c = '234' LIMIT 1 ];
        System.debug('orderOBJ>>'+oderObj);
        od.doNumber=oderObj.Name;
        od.billNumber='234';
        OrderDetailList.add(od);

        oinfor.orderDt = OrderDetailList;
        
        ApiUpdateClass.updateBill();
        System.assertEquals('234', od.billNumber);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the request body:

```
public static testmethod void setup() {
    Test.startTest();
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    // code
    request.requestBody = Blob.valueof('SAMPLE_OF_XML_REQUEST_BODY');
    RestContext.request = request;
    RestContext.response = res;
}
```

The following line causes System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null:

```
String xml = restRqst.requestBody.toString();
```

The test does not fails bacause you wrapped the code in try/catch block, look for the error message in the logs:

```
System.debug('error >> '+e.getMessage()+'at line >> '+e.getLineNumber());
```

Comment: The Test is Not failing, only code coverage issue, i am not getting how to Cover Code for DOM.Document lines

Comment: In you test method you need to specify the requestBody. Try to add the following code on line 11, and re-run the test: request.requestBody =Blob.valueof( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><addresses><address><BILLNUMBER>123</BILLNUMBER><DONUMBER>321</DONUMBER></address></addresses>');

Comment: DrWebber  Thanks, now its covered, thanks for your help.